# How to create a program that counts how many times each letter appears in a text?

Tags: python

Given a string as input, I need to output how many times each letter appears in the string.
I decided to store the data in a dictionary, with the letters as the keys, and the corresponding counts as the values.
How to Create a program that takes a string as input and output a dictionary, which represents the letter count that should be lowercase.

Sample Input

hello

Sample Output

{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: see `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
text = "This is the text to analyse"
dict = {}
for char in text:
    if char in dict:
        dict[char] += 1
    else:
        dict[char] = 1
print(dict)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks.
It was just needed to put input() in front of text

Comment: I think that's a solution that does the trick in an elegant way. I'm just throwing in the suggestion to use char.lower() instead of char, to make it non-case-sensitive.

Comment: see `collections.Counter`